# Moving a square around the screen in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I am asked to write an assembly code to draw a rectangle on the screen (the screen is 25 rows and 80 columns) and then to read a character from the user then moving the square around the screen if the character is 'r' or ending the program if the character is 'e'.

This is my code using `emu8086`:

```
code segment
start:

lea ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
; setting video mode
mov ah, 0
mov al, 03h
int 10h

mov al, 0             
mov ah, 6   

mov bh, 0h ;changing the color to black
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h     

mov dh, 8
mov dl, 20
mov bh, 0ffh ;changing the color to white
int 10h     

choose:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
cmp al, 'e'
je finish
cmp al, 'r'
je right ;unnecessary.


right:
mov al, 0             
mov ah, 6   

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h  

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 20
mov dh, 8
mov dl, 40
int 10h

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 40
mov dh, 8
mov dl, 60
int 10h    

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 60
mov dh, 8
mov dl, 79
int 10h     

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h 

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 8
mov cl, 60
mov dh, 16
mov dl, 79
int 10h   

mov bh, 0h
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h   

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 16
mov cl, 60
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79
int 10h

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h 

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 16
mov cl, 40
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 60
int 10h

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 16
mov cl, 20
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 40
int 10h

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h 

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 16
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 20
int 10h  

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 8
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 16
mov dl, 20
int 10h 

mov bh, 0h 
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79  
int 10h

mov bh, 0ffh
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 8
mov dl, 20
int 10h

jmp choose


finish:
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

This code works but I think that it can be shortened. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Word of advice on assembly coding - add lots of comments.  Then add a few more.

Answer (score 1):

You know that this:

```
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
```

Can also be expressed as this:

```
mov cx,0
```

Even faster, you can also do this:

```
xor cx, cx
```

Answer (score 0):

For reducing repeated blocks use a table and place the values that you need into it. Then get the values from the table and increase the pointer to the next part of values. Compare the pointer if it reached the end of the table, else jump back, for to get the next values form the table.
Example:

```
Table DW 0,0,2479h, 0FF00h,0820h,0 ; each of this entry contains a 16 bit value
Tab_End = $                        ; the offset address of this location

lea si, Table
mov ax, 0600h
AGAIN:
mov bx, [si]
mov cx, [si+2]
mov dx, [si+4]
add si, 6
; push si
int 10h
; pop si
cmp si, Tab_End
jnz AGAIN ; jump if the zeroflag is not set (and the compared values are not equal)
```

Hint: I think this software interrupt do not destroy our pointer in SI, but otherwise we have to save our register before und get it back after it.